# Direct output to pipe and stdout

Tags: bash, pipe, stdout, tee

Is there a way to pipe the output of a command and direct it to the `stdout` as well?

So for example, `fortune` prints a fortune cookie to `stdout` and  also pipes it to next command:

```
$ fortune | tee >(?stdout?) | pbcopy 
"...Unix, MS-DOS, and Windows NT (also known as the Good, the Bad, and
the Ugly)."
(By Matt Welsh)
```

Comment: I don't have my OSX at hand, what about `fortune | tee $(tty) | pbcopy`?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5677201/435605

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your assumption:

```
fortune | tee >(?stdout?) | pbcopy
```

won't work because the `fortune` output will be written to standard out twice, so you will double the output to `pbcopy`.

In OSX (and other systems support `/dev/std{out,err,in}`), you can check it:

```
$ echo 1 | tee /dev/stdout | sed 's/1/2/'
2
2
```

output `2` twice instead of `1` and `2`. `tee` outputs twice to `stdout`, and `tee` process's `stdout` is redirected to `sed` by the pipe, so all these outputs run through `sed` and you see double `2` here.

You must use other file descriptors, example standard error through `/dev/stderr`:

```
$ echo 1 | tee /dev/stderr | sed 's/1/2/'
1
2
```

or use `tty` to get the connected pseudo terminal:

```
$ echo 1 | tee "$(tty)" | sed 's/1/2/'
1
2
```

---

With `zsh` and `multios` option set, you don't need `tee` at all:

```
$ echo 1 >/dev/stderr | sed 's/1/2/'
1
2
```

Comment: `tee $(tty)` Or, y'know, `tee /dev/tty`

Comment: great explanation, top SO answer all around.

Comment: How come when you do `... tee /dev/stdout | sed...` it returns `2 2` and not `1 2`; doesn't `tee` run before `sed`? It makes no sense, especially since rest print what is expected at that point in pipe. Why is there a wormhole in the pipe? It messing me up man!

Comment: @user14492 not sure what you mean. `... tee /dev/stdout` causes result to be written to standard out _twice_, that's why you see `2 2`.

Answer (score 51):

`tee` always writes to its standard output. If you want to send the data to a command in addition to the terminal where the standard output is already going, just use process substitution with that command. (Note that in spite of starting with `>`, process substitution does not redirect standard output, the `tee` command sees it as a parameter.)

```
fortune | tee >(pbcopy)
```

Comment: This is good, also a good solution.

Comment: ~~Does anyone know what this redirection look like in fish shell?~~ The [docs](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/fish_for_bash_users.html?highlight=redirect#process-substitution) say _'There is no equivalent to `>(command)`.'_

Comment: This doesn't work in [Makefile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/356539/10451). Any other way to do it without process substitution?

Comment: @KamilDziedzic In a makefile, duplicating output is rarely a good idea in the first place, because rules with multiple outputs are poorly supported. Write the output to a file, and use separate rules for each way you want to post-process it.

Answer (score 1):

cuonglm said it all.

Just try:

```
fortune | tee "$(tty)" | pbcopy
```

`tty` should resolve to actual pseudo terminal (like `/dev/pts/99`)  in interactive session (i.e. in terminal), or *no a tty* in batch, at and daemon.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but `echo "$(tty)"` → /dev/pts/2, `seq 2 | tee "/dev/pts/2" | wc -l` → 1 2 2, but `seq 2 | tee "$(tty)" | wc -l` → 2

Comment: @PabloA yes `"$(tty)"` (quoted or not) resolv to **not a tty**. I am not sure how I tested it 5 years ago.