# Process substitution in GNU Makefiles

Tags: bash, shell, make, process-substitution

On a bash prompt, one can execute diff using pseudo files:

```
diff <(echo test) <(echo test)
```

Adding this as is into a Makefile fails:

```
all:
        diff <(echo test) <(echo test)
```

The error (hint: /bin/sh points to /bin/bash on this system):

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `diff <(echo test) <(echo test)'
```

What does it mean, and is there a way to still diff two outputs without using temporary files?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`/bin/sh` may be `bash` on your system, but when invoked as `sh`, `bash` will be running in POSIX mode (as if `POSIXLY_CORRECT` was defined, or it was started with `--posix`).

In this mode, process substitutions do not exist.

Solutions:

1. Use explicit temporary files:

   ```
   all:
       command1 >tmpfile
       command2 | diff tmpfile -
       rm -f tmpfile
   ```
2. Use a `bash -c` in-line script:

   ```
   all:
       bash -c 'diff <(command1) <(command2)'
   ```
3. Define the Makefile variable `SHELL` as `/bin/bash` (or whatever the path to `bash` is on your system):

   ```
   SHELL=/bin/bash
   ```

If you want portability, go with the first solution. If you are OK with a dependency on `bash`, pick the second.  If you additionally don't need to care about non-GNU `make` implementations, use the third.

---

Regarding setting `SHELL`:  The POSIX standard says that executables in Makefiles should be invoked with the `system()` C library function by `make`.  This function is not guaranteed to use the `SHELL` environment variable (in fact, doing so is discouraged by the standard). The standard also goes to some length to say that setting the Makefile variable `SHELL` should not affect the *environment variable* `SHELL`. In most implementations of `make` that I know of, however, the Makefile variable `SHELL` will be used to execute the commands.

The suggestion in [the Rationale for the `make` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/make.html#tag_20_76_18) is to use `bash -c`:

> The historical `MAKESHELL` feature, and related features provided by other `make` implementations, were omitted. In some implementations it is used to let a user override the shell to be used to run `make` commands. This was confusing; for a portable `make`, the shell should be chosen by the makefile writer. Further, a makefile writer cannot require an alternate shell to be used and still consider the makefile portable. While it would be possible to standardize a mechanism for specifying an alternate shell, existing implementations do not agree on such a mechanism, and makefile writers can already invoke an alternate shell by specifying the shell name in the rule for a target; for example:
>
> `python -c "foo"`

Comment: The info that using the SHELL variable is not POSIX conform was very helpful. Maybe it's still better to use `bash -c`.